# Kendo UI Grid - Won't display inherited columns

Tags: asp.net-mvc, grid, kendo-ui

For all my model entities I inherit a base class but when I try to place one of the inherited fields on the grid it just does not show them.
My workaround is to create a wrapper property on the derived class and now the grid displays the column.

ex:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public Guid RowId  { get; set; }
    public bool Deprecated { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }<br/>
    public DateTime DateTimeStamp { get; set; }
}

public class Foo : BaseEntity
{
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public string Description{ get; set; }
}
```

and the Grid setup

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Foo>()
.Name("Grid")
.Columns(cols =>
{
    cols.Bound(c => c.FooId);
    cols.Bound(c => c.Description);
    cols.Bound(c => c.DateTimeStamp).Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}").Title("Date/Time").Sortable(false);
.Pageable()
.Sortable()
```

)

To make it work I have to add a property referencing the property on the base class like this:

```
public class Foo : BaseEntity
{
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public string Description{ get; set; }
    public new DateTime DateTimeStamp
    {
        get { return base.DateTimeStamp; }
        set { base.DateTimeStamp = value; }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to avoid using the wrapper property on the derived class?

Thanks

Comment: How are you reading and hydrating the datasource?